# CSS min-width fixed and percentage

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering if I can have a section to have min width both as percentage and a fixed amount. Let me be more clear, I have the following html:

```
<body>
<main>
    <section id="home-section">
        ...Content...
    </section>
    <section id="team-section">
        ...Content...
    </section>
</main>
</body>
```

I have

```
section{
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Is there a way to have min-width as both: 100% and 600px?
So that if the viewport is less than 600px the width its 600px and if its more the min-width its 100%? (It can be more because of content)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only have to do this:

```
section {
    min-width: 600px;
}
```

it is automatically 100%, with a minimum of 600px.

Comment: Perfect. Ideal answer,

Answer (score 5):

The usual way is a bit different. You define for example:

```
width: 100%
max-width: 600px;
```

That way it will have the full width in smaller viewports, but never grow beyond 600px

P.S.: You wrote

> So that if the viewport is less than 600px the width its 600px

That way it would be wider than the viewport on smaller screens - I suppose this isn't what you want, is it?

Comment: I'm also curious if the OP meant 100% under 600px, haha.

Comment: No, I meant it right, I meant viewport less than 600px stick at 600px, longer than the current viewport

Comment: This was the logic I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Just specify a `width: 600px;` with your `min-width` and you should get what you're looking for.

This will make the section's 100% when the width is greater than 600px, and 600px when it is less than 600px, which is what you requested.

**CSS**

```
section {
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 600px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xLkgq5m8/)**

```css
section {
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <section id="home-section">
        ...Content...
    </section>
    <section id="team-section">
        ...Content...
    </section>
</main>
```